# Compare complex NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, compare, nsdictionary

I have a method [Order toJSON] that maps my class into a complex NSDictionary that have to be send to a server. To send it, I use `NSJsonSerialization` to convert it into a string.

The dictionary is of the form :

```
@{ 
  @"key": @"value", 
  @"order": @[ 
    @{ @"name": @"obj1", @"content": @[ ... ] },
    @{ @"name": @"obj2", @"content": @[ ... ] }
  ] 
}
```

I am writing unit tests to check that the NSDictionary is correct. The problem is that I actually don't know the order of the arrays. I can have obj2 before obj1.
When I am using `- [NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary]`, it sometimes fail due to the order of the objects.

Is there a way to compare those dictionaries without comparing the order of the arrays that it contains ? Sorting the array before may be an option, but it would be useless for anything else than testing, and it's quite complicated (and expensive).

Comment: Maybe doing a intersection (or union, or else) between the two arrays, and then compare them? I don't know if it's really fast.

Comment: Well I thought about that but the first array contains objects that contains another array. I'm looking for a more efficient solution, if possible at all.

Comment: Your are doing: Your own custom object to JSON. Could it be more interesting to check for equality with your own custom object instead? Writing appropriate custom `isEqual:`?

Comment: No because the only purpose of this comparison is to check the validity of the generated JSON (as an `NSDictionary`). I want my unit tests to tell me if I change the way the dictionary is created and I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that converting the arrays to `NSCountedSet`s will help here. `NSCountedSet` ignores the order of the objects, and also counts duplicate elements, so you will get the expected comparison.

Comment: See my edit, I need to serialize the whole dictionary to JSON, and `NSCountedSet` is not serializable by the `NSJSONSerialization` class. Is there another way to convert the whole dictionary into a string if it contains counted sets ?